Go recreation of STDOUT side-affects STDIN
Found tricky bug in Golang. Modification of STDOUT makes Read from STDIN impossible:
package main

import "os"

func main() {
        bts := make([]byte, 10)

        // Side-affects
        os.Create(os.Stdout.Name()) // comment to correct Read from STDIN

        n, err := os.Stdin.Read(bts)
        if err != nil {
           println("err: " + err.Error()) // err: read /dev/stdin: resource temporarily unavailable
           return
        }

        println(n)
}


// Result
err: read /dev/stdin: resource temporarily unavailable
// Expected
(no error)

What are you trying to achieve?

I struggled a problem where I couldn't read from STDIN. And I found a place with recreation of STDOUT (other stream). That impacted the STDIN stream. IMHO it shouldn't be that way. Streams are different and should be independent (like two different files).

I think it's not clear what the Create on the stdin is supposed to accomplish.  Normally stdin and stdout are connected to the same file (actually some /dev/ttyXX).  Calling create on a tty will have ... unexpected consequences

This is not a bug in Go. Your code damages the environment your program is running in, in this case the special file /dev/stdin, by running os.Create() on it. (You are probably running your code as privileged user, as regular users shouldn't be able to mess with /dev/.) Most language runtimes don't prevent you from damaging the environment; that's your responsibility as the programmer. You can also run os.RemoveAll("/") and delete all your system files, that wouldn't be a bug either.

I run os.Create() on STDOUT not on STDIN. But it damages  STDIN..

Okay, but that's still not a problem of Go. You can read the source and see for yourself that Go runtime does not do anything special about /dev/stdxxx. It just calls open(2). On Linux, /dev/stdxxx are soft-linked to /proc/self/fd/{0,1,2}. I have no idea what the kernel does when you O_CREAT one of these, but when your program runs from a terminal, all three fds point to the same object and perhaps that is what gets damaged.

It is running just fine ...  I am on Ubuntu 24.04 linux with go version go1.23.1
when I execute your code it correctly just sits there listening to stdin ... in same terminal when I type in

happyhalloween

and hit Enter it responds by outputting

10

then in same terminal it shows

ween


Command 'ween' not found, did you mean:

Above is correct since you allocate 10 bytes which it consumes then the code completes ... the extraneous input is not read by the code and so is simply output to the same terminal shell to which it says 'ween' not found
so from above all is well ... Please update your question to state which OS you are on ... is your setup somehow redirecting stdin elsewhere  ?  Perhaps the parent process from which your code is getting executed is redirecting stdin ... Is your code launched from supervisord or similar code launcher and watcher process ?
PS   always check for errors ... your call to os.Create should have its error checked ... it is error free here so your issue is elsewhere
